# How to setup eclipse and dspace for development?

Tags: dspace

I already tried [this tutorial](https://github.com/lyncode/dspace-springui/wiki/Configure-Development-Environment) but I'm not able to configure the development environment.

Comment: This page may be a better page to reference. https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/DSpace+IDE+-+Eclipse%2C+Git%2C+Maven%2C+and+Tomcat

Comment: Is there any video tutorial which show step by step whole process . https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/IDE+Integration+-+DSpace%2C+Eclipse+and+Tomcat+Video+Tutorial is not working

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which step exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a process that I follow.  My institution's DSpace instance is built off of the "DSpace Release" code base (only the "dspace" package is tracked in GitHub).  This recommendation assumes that a similar configuration is needed.

I have a solution that works for me, but the process that I use to populate the Java build path for a project feels complex.  I will describe that process below.

#### Build DSpace Code Base in Eclipse

- Download source from DSpace/DSpace
- Run maven build to obtain all jar files that will be needed: `mvn package`
- Create an Eclipse project that points to this code
- Each package's (dspace, dspace-api, dspace-rest) src/main/java folder should be configured as source folder
- Add jar files (generated in package target directories) to the project build path.  Create a classpath variable that points to the target directory and reference the generated jar files by "extending" the class path variable.  Most of these jar files can be found in the "lib" subdirectory in the target folder

#### Build your project dir

- Create your project source code directory including appropriate package directories (ideally only "dspace" is needed)
- Add project to source code control such as GitHub
- Create an eclipse project that points to this project directory
- On the Java build path, add a project dependency to the DSpace source code project
- Following the instructions listed above, add jar files (generated in the DSpace code base package target directories) to the project build path.

This project works well for those resources that get built into the target/lib directory.  There are some jar dependencies that only get built into package war files.  These are more tedious to include on the build path.

Comment: Hello @terrywb thankx for the answer but can you please tell me how to configure Each package (dspace, dspace-api, dspace-rest) src/main/java folder as source folder and i m not able to add jar files also is there is any command for this .

Comment: Source folders: Select your project.  Right click and select properties.  Click the "Java Build Properties".  Go to the Source tab.  Add the source folders there.

Comment: Jar files: from the Java Build Properties, click the library tab and add them there.

Comment: Help page for the Java Build Path: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm